# float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NaTType'

Tags: python

so I have a Dataframe which consists of 10 data frames I need to plot `sum_PP_LT` against `MS` but before this I want to add some random numbers to `sum_PP_LT` and `MS` just for plotting but I receive this error  what is wrong here in my code?

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

m = []
b = []
R2 = []

for df in dfs:
    X = df[["sum_PP_LT"]].values
    y = df["MS"].values
    slr = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
    r_sq = slr.score(X, y)
    R2.append(r_sq)
    b.append(slr.intercept_)
    m.append(slr.coef_)
    #add rand to x y and plot in the loop
    X = X.astype(float)
    x_random = pd.DataFrame(pd.to_numeric(np.random.random_sample(size = len(X))))
    X += x_random
    y = y.astype(float)
    y_random = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_sample(size = (1, len(y))))
    y += y_random
    df.plot(x = X, y = y, kind = "scatter")
    
    

print("intercept:", b)
print("R2:", R2)

coef_values = []
for i in range(len(m)):
    a = m[i].item()
    coef_values.append(a)
print("slope:", coef_values)
```

Comment: Does the DF have header and any empty element? Also, the error is for which line?

Comment: df doesn't have any empty elements
the error is for the line :
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-128-bcf701a01b1a> in <module>
     39     y_random = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_sample(size = (1, len(y))))
     40     y += y_random
---> 41     df.plot(x = X, y = y, kind = "scatter")
     42     #print(len(X))
     43

Comment: Are you sure that the length of X and Y are the same? Cause you plot the scatter plot of these.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you are trying to convert data to float that is incompatible with float conversion.

> NaT

["If a column is a DateTime and you have a missing value, then that value will be a NaT. NaT stands for Not a Time."](https://dev.to/discdiver/the-weird-world-of-missing-values-in-pandas-3kph)

So it seems "sum_PP_LT" or/and "MS" in your dataframe is DateTime and has missing values too.